# Реально ли так, чтобы на Mac был бы и Windows и OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, ос

Здраствуйте! Реально сделать так, чтобы была возможность на маке с Windows на OS X переключаться и в обратном...сейчас стоит OS X. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно, вот вам [первый](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj2nI79nYzYAhWBY1AKHZ1cCK8QFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapplelife.ru%2Fthreads%2Fmanual-ustanovka-maka-i-vindous-na-odin-xard-poshagovo.38295%2F&usg=AOvVaw0AVcAh-WoSDB9egzg7DI2Q) и [второй](http://systemagic.ru/windows-8/ustanovka-mac-os-x-i-windows-na-odin-zhyostkij-disk-hddssd/) гайд

Comment: А по-моему делается гораздо проще через bootcamp

Comment: Если уж так говорить, то вопрос изначально был задан некорректно. Я не понимаю, почему люди не могут гуглом пользоваться, это что так сложно?

Comment: Стоит написать в ответе ответ, а не ссылки. Ссылки учше постить комментариями.